# Is there a shortcut in vscode which takes me to the "last but one" edited line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

often editing lines of code involves in going back and forth between two different snippets of code.

And These snippets could either be at two different places in a file, or in two different files.

I know of a shortcut that takes me back to the last edited line (ctrl+k+q), but the last edited line would be the line which I just edited. and I want to go to the line which was edited before that. Is there any shortcut in vs code to achieve just this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe such a feature does not come with VSCode by default, but could be achieved using extensions. This extension does (partially) what you are looking for -  [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mishkinf.vscode-edits-history) (use Ctrl +/- for jumping).
I am personally using [bookmarks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks) for that, but it requires manual toggling.